# Magento: shipping_tablerate table in db is empty after importing tables from backend

Tags: php, database, ce-1.8.1.0, html, table-rates

shipment method extensions based on table rates like `Matrixrates` won't show in frontend. i disabled other extensions but nothing changed. no log and no error. i checked out `shipping_tablerate` table in database and it was empty. and nothing added after reimporting data.

this is one line of `tablerate.csv` that i am trying to import to the Matrixrates:

```
Country,Region/State,City,"Zip/Postal Code From","Zip/Postal Code To","Weight From","Weight To","Shipping Price","Delivery Type"
IRN,*,*,1199000000,1911000000,1,5.9999,11000,Iran Post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebShopApps MatrixRate` table rates stores in `matrixrates-tablerate` in DB.